# How to caching images in GWT with no-cache property in header?

Tags: javascript, gwt, caching, web, client-side

**How to caching images in GWT with no-cache property in header ? I can't make changes in server and i need cache images in GWT side .**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually need a mix and match of client and server side code. Some client side concepts are explained previously here - [GWT Caching Concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138767/gwt-caching-concept)

Image handling via ClienBundle helps in caching - https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle

You can pick up some mode ideas from pagespeed to optimize image processing/bandwidth usage - https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/payload